# Parsing the JSON data using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, json, parsing

i'm having a problem with parsing the json data from hello.json to the current html file.

how do i get the data of investors, events and price from hello.json to three individual arrays.

http://compliantbox.com/mobile/optionsedge/hi.html

please help me out!!!

here is my html code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>

    $.getJSON("http://compliantbox.com/mobile/optionsedge/hello.json?jsoncallback=?",
      {},
      function(data) { alert(data);  $.each(data.items, function(i,item){ alert(); });
      });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and here is my json code:

```
{ "data": 

{ 

"current_condition":[{

        "investors": [{"active"},{"agressive"},{"conservative"},{"day trader"},{"very active"}], 

        "events": [{"3 months"},{"weekly"},{"monthly"},{"leaps"},{"heaps"}], 

        "price": [{"4"},{"3"},{"9"},{"5"},{"2"}]

    } ] }}
```

Comment: It already should be. Nothing happens when I go to your page and you have not provided a testcase, so I cannot comment further.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: You should really look at the console if you're doing Ajax and it's not working.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal
when you open the file in chrome you can see that the hello.json is being called but the data in it not parsing............

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 3**: I just actually looked at your linked page (**always** copy relevant code into the question itself), and here's your problem:

```
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
  $("<html/>").attr("src", item.event);
  if ( i == 3 ) return true;
});
```

There is no `data.items` in the resulting object deserializing the (now-valid) JSON you're pointing to. There's no `items` at all. Your JSON describes an object with one property, `data`, which in turn has a property `current_conditions`, which is an array with one entry, an object with the properties `investors`, `events`, and `price`. See my code from Update 2 for how to interact with it.

**Update 2**: If you change your JSON to make it valid, jQuery will work. I mean, thousands of sites use this everyday... [Live example](http://jsbin.com/uwuca5) with your data massaged to make it valid.

**Update**: Now that you've posted your JSON, we can see that it's invalid. Check out the [JSON](http://json.org) site and the [JSONlint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) tool. Your `investors`, `events`, and `price` arrays all contain entries in the form `{"active"}`, which is an invalid object entry.

---

**Original Answer**:

If you're using jQuery's [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function (or [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) or one of its other wrappers), it should be parsed by the time you see it. If you ever have to parse a JSON string yourself, use [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). Details:

#### `ajax` and its wrappers

Expanding on the `ajax` thing: If you're getting back a string and expecting an object (e.g., the result of parsing the JSON), ensure that the server is returning the correct content-type ("application/json"). If you can't control the server and it's sending back the wrong content-type, you can override the server by giving `ajax` a `dataType` option.

If it's not working, you might want to check -- is the [JSON](http://json.org) really [valid JSON](http://www.jsonlint.com/)? Because there's a lot of not-quite-JSON out there. For instance, this is valid JSON:

```
{
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": "x"
}
```

This is **not**:

```
{
    foo: 1,
    bar: 'x'
}
```

A strict parser may reject the latter, because it's invalid (in a couple of different ways).

Example - normal, server-is-configured-correctly version:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "yoururl",
   success: function(data) {
       // Here, `data` is already an object if the response was
       // JSON and the server gave the correct content-type
   }
});
```

Example - Forcing the data type:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "yoururl",
   dataType: "json",           // <== The new bit
   success: function(data) {
       // Here, `data` is already an object if the response was
       // parseable JSON
   }
});
```

or

```
$.getJSON("yoururl", function(data) {
   // Here, `data` is already an object if the response was
   // parseable JSON
});
```

#### Parsing your own string:

```
var str = '{"foo": 1, "bar": "x"}'; // A JSON string
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(str);    // The resulting object
```

Comment: It is actually invalid JSON. It contains things like: {"active"}, which is declaring an identifier with no value. Probably a problem with the JSON encoder.

Comment: @digitalFresh: He hadn't posted it before. Yeah, that's pretty invalid. :-)

Comment: @digitalFresh no luck bro, i changed the json to a valid one but still the data is not parsing

Comment: @Prateek Raj: Your question still shows invalid JSON. I've added a second update to the answer above showing that yes, it **does** work if the data is made valid. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: @Prateek Raj: I just added Update 3, but it looks like you've already accepted (I'm guessing you looked at Update 2 and figured it out).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder   
Thank you very much dude.......
However wen i'm trying to use the htmlcode from my system it's not working.
Can you please send me the source code . . . . .
Thank you.

Comment: @Prateek Raj: I'm afraid I have no idea what you're trying to do with that code. You're probably best off asking a new question saying what it is you're trying to do with the data once you've loaded it, showing what you're doing, and then asking how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid.

http://compliantbox.com/mobile/optionsedge/hello.json?jsoncallback=?

http://www.jsonlint.com/

That is why the parsing is not working.

As @Skilldrick pointed out in the Question comments, you should check the console when you're doing AJAX and it's not working; doing so would have revealed the syntax error exception.

Comment: More specifically, `{"foo": "bar"}` is a valid object, `{"foo"}` isn't (property value is missing).

Comment: Indeed. He likely meant `["foo"]`. But we don't want to give too much away, eh? :P Plenty of references for him to read up on (http://json.org/).

Comment: no luck bro, i changed the json to a valid one but still the data wont parse

Comment: @Prateek Then you have a new issue. Please obtain some error message from your console and file an appropriate question regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the page you liked to and the JSON file it then calls, I would say that this would get you what you need:

```
function(data) {
    var lists = data['data']['current_condition'][0];

    var investors = lists['investors'],
        events = lists['events'],
        price = lists['price'];
}
```